Callout[] unpredictably fails to display
Callout[] sometimes shows the desired info, sometimes doesn't. For the following, I see the "P" callout, but not the "Si".
ListPlot[{Callout[{1.7404133545310005`, 0.9943079488168214`}, 
   "Si"], {1.7431478537360878`, 
   0.996636142267291`}, {1.7458823529411753`, 0.9934257981652584`}, 
  Callout[{2.0193322734499195`, 1.031526392234193`}, 
   "P"], {2.022066772655007`, 
   1.0063035818317037`}, {2.0248012718600945`, 0.9795130652397709`}}, 
 PlotRange -> All]

Is there a way to coax it to show all callouts?
Mathematica 13.2.1.0 on OS X.
Edit:
The answer by @eldo works for the above example, but here's a more complicated case where it doesn't.
ListPlot[{
  {1.4806359300476934`, 0.14236806093735052`}, {1.483370429252781`, 
   0.14641432590006115`}, {1.4861049284578685`, 0.14671982445757584`},
   Callout[{1.488839427662956`, 0.14655823821647976`}, 
   "Al"], {1.4915739268680432`, 
   0.14593092805810623`}, {1.4943084260731307`, 
   0.1448452835994791`}, {1.4970429252782183`, 
   0.14331458860400498`}, {1.4997774244833055`, 
   0.14135774163106088`}, {1.7240063593004757`, 
   0.9620739989785534`}, {1.7267408585055632`, 
   0.9682751824159199`}, {1.7294753577106508`, 
   0.9797106912957093`}, {1.732209856915738`, 
   0.9930861265231284`}, {1.7349443561208255`, 
   0.994391291146156`}, {1.737678855325913`, 0.9971437717246525`}, 
  Callout[{1.7404133545310005`, 0.9943079488168214`}, 
   "Si"], {1.7431478537360878`, 
   0.996636142267291`}, {1.7458823529411753`, 
   0.9934257981652584`}, {1.7486168521462628`, 
   0.991760651450785`}, {1.7513513513513501`, 
   0.978167989451046`}, {1.7540858505564376`, 
   0.9699765022955094`}, {1.7568203497615251`, 0.9602518456977506`}, 
  Callout[{2.0193322734499195`, 1.031526392234193`}, 
   "P"], {2.022066772655007`, 
   1.0063035818317037`}, {2.0248012718600945`, 0.9795130652397709`}}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]]

The Al and P points are called out, but the Si point isn't.

As explained in the documentation for Callout:

Callouts are pruned to avoid collisions.

You have many points close together around "Si", that is why the callout isn't shown.
Use Callout[..., LabelVisibility -> All] to force showing the callout.
If you don't want to type this every time, set it globally with:
SetOptions[Callout, LabelVisibility -> All];



Add some PlotRangePadding
ListPlot[{Callout[{1.7404133545310005`, 0.9943079488168214`}, 
   "Si"], {1.7431478537360878`, 
   0.996636142267291`}, {1.7458823529411753`, 0.9934257981652584`}, 
  Callout[{2.0193322734499195`, 1.031526392234193`}, 
   "P"], {2.022066772655007`, 
   1.0063035818317037`}, {2.0248012718600945`, 0.9795130652397709`}},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]]



Works for that example, but not for others. I'll have to update the question, I guess.

$Version

Clear["Global`*"]

Place the "Si" Callout Below
ListPlot[
 {{1.4806359300476934`, 0.14236806093735052`}, {1.483370429252781`, 
   0.14641432590006115`}, {1.4861049284578685`, 0.14671982445757584`},
  Callout[{1.488839427662956`, 0.14655823821647976`}, "Al"],
  {1.4915739268680432`, 0.14593092805810623`}, {1.4943084260731307`, 
   0.1448452835994791`}, {1.4970429252782183`, 
   0.14331458860400498`}, {1.4997774244833055`, 
   0.14135774163106088`}, {1.7240063593004757`, 
   0.9620739989785534`}, {1.7267408585055632`, 
   0.9682751824159199`}, {1.7294753577106508`, 
   0.9797106912957093`}, {1.732209856915738`, 
   0.9930861265231284`}, {1.7349443561208255`, 
   0.994391291146156`}, {1.737678855325913`, 0.9971437717246525`},
  Callout[{1.7404133545310005`, 0.9943079488168214`}, "Si", Below],
  {1.7431478537360878`, 0.996636142267291`}, {1.7458823529411753`, 
   0.9934257981652584`}, {1.7486168521462628`, 
   0.991760651450785`}, {1.7513513513513501`, 
   0.978167989451046`}, {1.7540858505564376`, 
   0.9699765022955094`}, {1.7568203497615251`, 0.9602518456977506`},
  Callout[{2.0193322734499195`, 1.031526392234193`}, "P"],
  {2.022066772655007`, 1.0063035818317037`}, {2.0248012718600945`, 
   0.9795130652397709`}},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02]]


